# inspect element by keeping session in appium desktop?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am using appium desktop.I am automating chat application(like hike, whatsApp) which begins with registration module.Whenever i need to inspect the element in the application ,have to cross the registration.Then only i can enter into another page(like chat page, group chat page) in application.I want to directly navigate to any page(like chat page, group chat page) by maintaining session.Any way to maintain session???

Comment: Your question is not clear? Include some screenshot and example.

Comment: can you please tell more about what do you mean by navigate to any pages. are there multiple pages. may be some next upcoming pages depends on previous page. can you got success in manual doing such thing.

Comment: Thanks and sry all, hope my question is clear now